# Text line jumping up all the time - why?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

When I'm editing the text I created earlier, now all in a sudden the line jumps up all the time like this:

https://i.gyazo.com/ea8fd33bf293afbe53846454263df746.mp4

This happens when I delete some of the existing text like in the gif, but also when I add new text or when I just write something new instead. It's annoying because the space is supposed to be there.

Hope someone can explain to me what I'm doing wrong.

I know you guys put a LOT of effort in the answers here, so thank you in advance :)

Comment: Maybe there is some missing information to understand what happens:
• Copy the text in Photoshop and paste it in a Illustrator's text box > **Menu  Type** > **Show Hidden Characters**, to see what is the complete writing and add a screenshot to the question
• Also include a screenshots of the Photoshop's text and paragraph panels with the text you refer selected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing that some part of the text in that line has different Leading [image] and when you delete all those words, you delete the characters that have that bigger leading.

It could be just one character or even an empty space that has a bigger leading than the rest of it.

You can insert cursor at the beginning and repeatedly click right arrow key until you find the point where the leading changes. You can also select large chunks of text and if the leading value shows up empty, it means there are multiple different values in the selection. So you can use that to track down the problem area quicker without having to click right arrow key a thousand times.